# Is there a responsive grid system in Magento's new 1.9 RWD theme

Tags: magento, responsive-design, magento-1.9

Is there a responsive grid system in Magento's new 1.9 RWD theme?

If this new theme is not using a grid system how is the theme responsive?

I've looked through the CSS & SCSS &  I can't find one?

Answer (score 0):

The responsiveness can be found in the skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/styles.css file for the RWD theme. This theme is using media queries. See below for an example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 770px) {
  .notice-cookie {
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .notice-cookie .notice-text {
    max-width: 82%;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
}
```

You can read more about media queries here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries